# What’s the best way to follow the fixed income market

Tags: fixed, income

I’ve just started a front office job in the fixed income market and find it very hard to follow the market in general. Im pretty comfortable with equities as I would know how stocks have moved, and understand fundamental expectations vs earnings print of companies. But fixed income market seem more complex. What are the different points that one has to be aware of in order to understand, track and follow the fixed income market?

Comment: Is this in rates or credit?

Comment: Fabozzi's Handbook of Fixed Income is the bible of bonds